# Restarting a Finished Thread Causes Crash (Android SDK)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

The title pretty much explains the issue.

I have a button that when I press toggles on/off this thread.  It turns it on and off successfully... once, then it crashes if I try to turn it on again.

```
private Thread dataThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        while(transmitPackets){
                Log.d("Test","DERP");
        }
    }
});
```

and where its run...

```
toggleButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            transmitPackets = !transmitPackets;
            if( transmitPackets ) {
                toggleButton.setText("Pause");
                dataThread.start();
            }
            else {
                toggleButton.setText("Transmit");
            }
        }
    });
```

transmitPackets is the boolean toggled by the button press.  Named as such because this app will eventually be sending data over a network. The thread uses it to terminate as well.

The stack trace generated by the app crash isn't particularly helpful in figuring out how to fix it to me as it just says it crashed on restarting the thread--which was evident by the problem itself.

I'm new to the Android SDK and threading in Java both so I don't know where I could be going wrong.  This seems to be the simplest implementation of a thread possible which is where I'm starting before I try to do anything funky with the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to move your `DataThread` code into the `setOnClickListener` code, as you only create one thread, so when you 'start' it again, it can't, as it is done. You should declare `DataThread` where you do now, but set it in the listener

Answer (score 2):

> It turns it on and off successfully... once, then it crashes if I try to turn it on again.

Indeed. You can't start a thread which has already finished. You'll need to create a new thread, and start that.

Note that the information that you can't restart a thread which has already been started should have been clear to you from:

- The stack trace
- The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29):

  > Throws `IllegalThreadStateException` if the Thread has been started before

When something causes an exception, you should **always** read the exception message (and stack trace, as there may be causal information there) and documentation carefully.

Comment: Every answer here got it, thanks guys!  I just had the thread get created in the OnClickListener and it's working beautifully.

For what it's worth, that exception is not in the stack trace the crash generated.  I appreciate the help either way.

Comment: @Wuzseen: Well what *does* the stack trace look like? You should take a step back and analyze why you weren't able to diagnose this yourself. You say the stack trace "isn't particularly helpful" - but perhaps if you'd actually copied it into your question, we could have helped you see how it *is* helpful...

Answer (score 2):

Once thread is done, its gone. You can't restart. You may need to create new thread. Without stack trace, hard to suggest anything.

calling `start()` on thread doesn't mean you are restarting thread. That means you are starting new thread.

Issue could be something else. Post stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

A better Implementation would be

```
private Thread dataThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run() {
    while(true){

    if(transmitPackets){
       Log.d("Test","DERP");
       transmitPackets = false;
    }
  }
}
});
```

that way the thread keeps going, and all you do is change truth value
of the transmitPackets value so it will run

Comment: Except you should make a new thread to hold this dataThread Thread, so that way it doesnt run on the GUI thread at all. I suggest a new class, and that way you can call a method transmitData(), and that class will set transmitPackets to true

Comment: And this also means that as long as your app is running, the device will not sleep, even if the screen is off or you have `transmitPackets` as false; CPU usage will peg as well. Empty spinning loops still eat up cycles

Comment: seemed easier to explain because he is new to the sdk rather than trying to explain an AsyncTask.

Comment: I won't lie, I've used similar code for quick tests as it is faster to write, but only as code that was temporary - it shouldn't be considered for production code